# C++ Parent class with virtual methods implemented in 2 different child classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

It was hard to make the title very clear about the subject, but I will try to explain the context (and there is some of the code down below). Note: I have seen similar questions answered, but they only treated the cases with 1 child class. So they didn't really help in my case, because I have 2 child classes.

**Context:** 
I have a parent class Shape that has 2 child: Circle and Square. 
I will have a vector of Shape objects, but these Shape objects will actually only be either Circle objects or Square objects. I need the Circle and Square classes to have the same parent class so that I can store them both in the same vector.

The trick is that I will need to use the Shape objects in the vector to call methods implemented in either the Circle class or the Square class, therefore, I need to have a "virtual" version of those methods in the parent class Shape.

**Here is a simplified part of the code for my classes:**

Shape.h :

```
class Shape{
public:
    std::string getColor();

    virtual int getRadius() = 0; //Method implemented in Circle
    virtual int getHeight() = 0; //Method implemented in Square
    virtual int getWidth() = 0;  //Method implemented in Square

protected:
    std::string color;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
public:
    int getRadius();

private:
    int radius;
};

class Square : public Shape{
public:
    int getHeight();
    int getWidth();

private:
    int height;
    int width;
};
```

In Shape.cpp I have something like this:

```
std::string Shape::getColor(){
    return color;
}

int Circle::getRadius(){
    return radius;
}

int Square::getHeight(){
    return height;
}

int Square::getWidth(){
    return width;
}
```

The **errors** occurs in the main.cpp when I want to create Circle and Square objects:

```
Circle *c = new Circle(...);//Error: cannot instantiate abstract class
                            //pure virtual function "Shape::getHeight" has no overrider
                            //pure virtual function "Shape::getWidth" has no overrider


Square *s = new Square(...);//Error: cannot instantiate abstract class
                            //pure virtual function "Shape::getRadius" has no overrider
```

So it seems like I would need a declaration of "getRadius" in the Square class and a declaration of "getHeight" and "getWidth" in the Circle class...

I tried adding them with virtual, but that makes Circle and Square abstract classes, so I can't create any objects with them.

Is there a way to make this work?

This is my first question posted on stackoverflow. I hope everything is clear. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You must at least define a body for the pure virtual functions you declared in `Shape` in each of the derived classes or those classes become abstract base classes and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Also, you should inherit from `Shape` not `Shapes`.

Comment: No, this attempt at design makes no sense whatsoever, and there is no way to add any. A parent class must only have interface that is common to all child classes, full stop, no ifs or buts or howevers. Look up "is-a relationship".

Comment: As above, you should rethink your design instead of trying to make badly designed classes to compile. The shape class should only contain members which are common for all shapes. Even an empty base class would be better than your current one.

Comment: @Marian If I do that, I wouldn't be able to use my parent class to call functions. I would need to store both child classes in the same vector, but I don't think I can do that. You are right though, I might need to rethink it all.

Comment: How do you know which functions you can actually call? If you are trying to call getRadius, then you must be *somehow* sure you have a Circle at hand.  If you are sure, why are you holding a Shape pointer and not a Circle pointer? If you are not sure, why are you calling getRadius? *That's* the problem with your design, not the technical aspect of what gunction is declared how. Solve it, and the technical aspects will solve themselves. Or don't solve it, and keep stumbling over more and more technical things. Your choice.

Comment: There is an identifier in each class (a typedef enum) that I can check to see which of Circle or Square it is.

Comment: @JLuc5 having an enum to show the type of object is exactly why you would implement virtual functions instead (as you want common parent class so that you can treat all objects in the same way, as mentioned above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your virtual methods are not really good candidates for virtual methods** because they have specific functionality for one class but no use for the other.

Good example of virtual method would be something implemented by each class but with different functionality or result, like `virtual int area()` or `virtual bool intersects( Shape * otherShape )` and so on.

Anyway, this is how you would get your code compiled (with some extras):

shape:

```
class Shape{
public:
    std::string getColor();

    Shape() {}
    virtual ~Shape() {}

    virtual int getRadius() { return 0; }  // no pure virtual
    virtual int getHeight() { return 0; }  // no pure virtual
    virtual int getWidth() { return 0; }   // no pure virtual

protected:
    std::string color;
};


class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle( int r )
        : Shape()
        , radius( r )
    {}  

    Circle() : Circle( 0 ) {}
    ~Circle() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    int getRadius() override { return radius; }; 

private:
    int radius;
};
```

square:

```
class Square : public Shape {
public:
    Square( int h, int w )
        : Shape()
        , height( h )
        , width( w )
    {}  

    Square() : Square( 0, 0 ) {}
    ~Square() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    int getHeight() override { return height; }
    int getWidth() override { return width; }

private:
    int height;
    int width;
};
```

test:

```
int main() {
    using shapes = std::vector< Shape * >;

    shapes s;
    s.push_back( new Circle( 10 ) );
    s.push_back( new Square() );
    s.push_back( new Square( 1, 3 ) );
    s.push_back( new Circle() );

    for ( Shape * sh : s ) {
        std::cout
            << " r " << sh->getRadius()
            << " h " << sh->getHeight()
            << " w " << sh->getWidth()
            << std::endl;
    }       

    for ( Shape * sh : s ) { delete sh; } s.clear();
}
```

output:

```
r 10 h 0 w 0
r 0 h 0 w 0
r 0 h 1 w 3
r 0 h 0 w 0
virtual Circle::~Circle()
virtual Square::~Square()
virtual Square::~Square()
virtual Circle::~Circle()
```

Here is a better use of virtual methods with area example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Shape {
    Shape() {}
    virtual ~Shape() {}

    virtual double area() = 0;
};
```

extend with different area implementation:

```
struct Circle : public Shape {
    Circle( int r )
        : Shape()
        , radius( r )
    {}

    Circle() : Circle( 0 ) {}
    ~Circle() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    virtual double area() override { return radius * radius * 3.14; }

    int radius;
};

struct Square : public Shape {
    Square( int h, int w )
        : Shape()
        , height( h )
        , width( w )
    {}

    Square() : Square( 0, 0 ) {}
    ~Square() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    virtual double area() override { return height * width; }

    int height;
    int width;
};
```

test

```
int main() {
    using shapes = std::vector< Shape * >;

    shapes s;
    s.push_back( new Circle( 1 ) );
    s.push_back( new Square( 1, 1 ) );
    s.push_back( new Square( 2, 3 ) );
    s.push_back( new Circle( 2 ) );

    for ( Shape * sh : s ) {
        std::cout << sh->area() << std::endl;
    }

    for ( Shape * sh : s ) { delete sh; } s.clear();
}
```

output:

```
3.14
1
6
12.56
virtual Circle::~Circle()
virtual Square::~Square()
virtual Square::~Square()
virtual Circle::~Circle()
```

Comment: That sounds like an interesting way to do it. I will test it in my code tomorrow. I have a quick question for you. Is "for ( Shape * sh : s )" the same thing as doing it with an iterator: "for(vector<Shape*>::iterator sh = objects.begin(); sh != objects.end(); ++sh){ (*sh)->area()}.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JLuc5 yes it's the same as iterator

Comment: This will get the code compiled, but will not add a iota of *sense* to it. You can get all kinds of garbage to compile. The goal is not to have that, but to have a sensible design you can work with.

Comment: @n.m. firstly I answered the questions, secondly I provided a better example for use of virtual functions in this example

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder, as is "solution". You've got the code to compile and do what is asked in the question, that's about it. You have not provided a solid basis for further development of the code, while promoting all the wrong ideas about object-oriented design. The question looks like a homework and if I were grading your answer it would get an F. Sorry.

Comment: You're both right. Thanks for the answer stefanB, and thanks n.m. for pointing out what is wrong in my design  :D

Comment: And its not an homework, Im trying to draw stuff with OpenFrameworks and I needed a vector containing all my shapes. That's why I need the parent class. I guess I could have 2 vectors, 1 for Circles and 1 for Squares, but it's not as nice  ;)

Comment: @JLuc5 This is a question in and of itself. How do you implement a drawing program in the object-oriented fashion? Normally you do need a vector of Shape pointers, not two vectors for different kinds of shapes. What if you have 40 kinds of shapes? This is not at all uncommon. You can ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @n.m. well I'm sorry if you don't like the suggestion about virtual function that hides the details of what needs to be done for each class, or perhaps you did not read the whole answer? ... I keep scrolling my fingers off down the page and I don't see your answer - I, and anybody else I'm sure, would upvote right away if you provided interesting points ...

Comment: The design is broken and needs to be replaced. Your virtual funcs  try (unsuccessfully) to hide the inconvenient fact that there can be *no* useful implementation for e.g. getRadius in a Square. But as the program grows, it will surface and bite you. The only sensible thing to do is to disallow entirely calling getRadius on a Square. This means you need to remove it from Shape. But this leaves Shape with no methods, right? Why do you need Shape class, then? Perhaps other methods can be useful in Shape? This is the sort of questions I'm trying to get asked. *Then* I can answer them.

Comment: @n.m. if you actually looked at my answer you would see that in my suggested class structure there is no virtual getRadius, in my suggested solution class `Shape` only has an example virtual `area()` method to show how it could be done better ... exactly as what you suggests in your comments

Comment: Ugh, I'm terribly sorry I have somehow totally missed your second solution. I swear I have looked multiple times on your answer and it still flew over my head :( I can only blame the small screen of my phone, I should have used a normal computer to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the difference between `pure virtual` and just `virtual` functions. `Pure virtual` functions are essentially placeholder functions with **no** body. Your base class of shape is better suited for plain `virtual` functions, which are functions that can but don't have to be changed in subclasses. Take out the `= 0` part in the function declaration to make the functions just plain `virtual` functions.

Comment: This is what I did before, but then, don't I need to give them an empty body in my Shape.cpp file?
And if I do that, then when I call the methods from the Shape objects in the vector, won't it use the function as defined with the empty body? Instead of using the right ones from either the Circle or Square class?

I could add some code to explain how I want to use the vector of Shape objects.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you headed in the right direction. By making your members not pure virtual you can implement them if you want in the derived classes but you do not have to.

```
class Shape{
    public:
    std::string getColor();

    virtual int getRadius(); //Method implemented in Circle
    virtual int getHeight(); //Method implemented in Square
    virtual int getWidth();  //Method implemented in Square

protected:
    std::string color;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
public:
    int getRadius();

private:
    int radius;
};

class Square : public Shape{
public:
    int getHeight();
    int getWidth();

private:
    int height;
    int width;
};
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but then, it means that I have to give those virtual methods in "Shape" a body right? I could make it an empty body, but then whenever I call for example getRadius() from a Shape object in my vector, it will use that empty body instead of the one from the Circle class, no?
This might be weird, but I would need to be able to call getRadius() using a Shape object in my vector (*that object would have initially been created as a Circle*) and make it do what is defined in Circle::getRadius(){...}

Comment: @JLuc5 If by shape object you mean, `Shape myShape` then yes, it will call the empty body. However, `Shape *myShape = new Circle()` will not.

Comment: Shape *myShape = new Circle(); ... I might need to try that out. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks